# How to detect SMS only when application is running in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. In my application, I need to detect incoming SMS.
I have tried a sample example with broadcast receiver. But the problem with broadcast receiver is that even when your application is not running it detects sms. My requirement is to detect sms on when my application is running.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you defining the broadcast receiver in manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are 2 Solutions to your problem:** (**[See This for refernce](http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.com/2012/05/broadcast-receiver-two-ways-to.html)**)

### 1. By Registering Dynamic Broadcast receiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      // Do your sms receive logic here    
  }
}
```

And Register this Receiver in your activity like this:

```
 // Global
 BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new MyReceiver();

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(smsReceiver , new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);        
    super.onPause();
}
```

### 2. By Checking that your app is running or not in your static Broadcast Receiver:

If you want to implement this method you have to do alot more work:

a) Add **"android.permission.GET_TASKS"** permission in Manifest

b) Call this method in your broadcast receiver's onReceive() Method **before doing anything**

```
public boolean checkRunningApps() {
    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTasks = mActivityManager
            .getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    int pos = -1;

    // Checking that your app is in running task list or not
    for (int i = 0; i < runningTasks.size(); i++) {
        if ((runningTasks.get(i).topActivity.getPackageName()
                .contains(AppSettings.REQUIRED_PACKAGENAME))) {
            isAppRunning = true;
            pos = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (pos == -1) {
        // App is not running, do nothing
        return false;
    }

    if (pos >= 0) {
        // App is running, do your logic here
        // If you want to check that app is on top, check for only 0 position of runningTasks arrayList
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

> If this method returns **true then do your logic**, else **do nothing**.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to track whether your app is visible to user or not. You have to track it by yourself simply counting screens when they enter onResume() and onPause(). When the app hits onResume() of any activity, increment a counter and when hits to onPause() decrement. You can simply create a base Activity and place those counting system in it and extend it from every Activity you created in your application.

Check out the Android Activity Lifecycle.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

*Try this !!*

***Your broadcast receiver must specify android:exported="false" for not receiving broadcasts created outside your own application.***

**`Sample` broadcast receiver is defined in the manifest as follows:**

```
<receiver
    android:name=".IncomingSmsBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Not working...If I do this change then it is not detecting the incoming message.